# how to store current date/time in xml using php dom

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am creating XML files using PHP and DOM and populating the values of some XML elements with MySql data and that works fine. Before saving those XML files, I need to be able to dynamically store the current date/time in an XML element, which would look while done statically (i.e. hard-coded) like this:

```
$eventdatetime=$xml->createElement("eventdatetime", "12 jun 2017");
$eventdatetime->setAttribute("standarddatetime", "2017-06-12T23:00:00-01:00");
```

I have tested it with `getDate()` values, but couldn't get it to work, so I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) for that:

```
$now = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$eventdatetime = $xml->createElement("eventdatetime", strtolower($now->format("j M y")));
$eventdatetime->setAttribute("standarddatetime", $now->format("c"));
```

You can change the timezone to whatever applies, that will influence what the "-01:00" or "+08:00" will be. The `strtolower()` is to compensate for the `M` format which returns the month name with a capital (i.e. "Jun" instead of "jun").